# error copying files after rooting

Tags: root-access, permissions

I rooted my micromax a27 a few days back. It installed an app Kinguser to give root permission.

Earlier it was working fine.

I did a factory reset last night.

Now, when I try to copy file to root folders like `/system/media/` directory. It gives error as `Permission Denied`.

Please help how to recover root access.

I am using `ES explorer` with root access enabled.

Comment: Have you re-mounted `/system` before trying to copy? That partition usually is mounted read-only – so of course *write* permission is denied.

Comment: how to _re-mount_ `/system` ?

Comment: Multiple ways: `adb remount`, or (via `adb shell` or a terminal app after becoming root) `mount -o remount,rw /system`, or using root-filemanagers which have this capability built-in.

Comment: I think i have lost root on my phone. as after checking root status using `root checker` is says `Not Rooted`

Comment: I wonder why ES is not explaining about that then. But if `root checker` fails, there must be some issue with root. "How to root the A27" would be a separate question (it's not yet listed in our [rooting index](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1184/16575)).

Comment: Yeah you lost root when you did the factory-reset, Kinguser doesn't hold root. Just re-install it again to acquire root once more.

Comment: But don't know how to re-install or uninstall Kinguser as it is installed in root folder which is now write-protected.

Answer (score 1):

In es file manager, slide the menu out and tap on "root explorer" (not the switch) and choose mount rw. Then tap on the radio button in the rw column for all rows. Now you should be able to write to those partitions.